# Running Knex queries taking longer in files vs REPL

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, knex.js

I'm trying to seed some data to a database:

```
// seed.js
var Knex = require("knex");
var database = require("./config").database;
var knex = Knex.initialize(database);

knex("users").insert({
    first_name: "John",
    last_name: "Doe"
}).exec(function (err, id) {
    console.log("Fulfilled", id);
});

// returns [ 1 ]
```

My problem is that if I put this in a file and running it using `node seed.js`, it executes the `console.log` then it seems to be waiting longer (about 20 seconds) before it returns the shell prompt. Doing the same in REPL where the result is instantaneous.

Is there a reason why my code will wait 20 seconds before it shows me the command prompt again if I run it in shell vs executing this in a REPL?

Comment: I feel like I'm not seeding to the database correctly. What would be the proper way to seed to the DB with knex? Do I need to put this in a migration?

Answer (score 1):

by default node won't give you the console back until the script is totally completely done, while inside the node repl it gives back the repl as soon as the last line stops blocking.

In the repl you actually get focus back before the console.log prints, while with the script it also has to wait for stuff to close up, you can speed it along by adding `process.exit(0)` after the console.log.

Comment: Thanks @Calvin. I might be using Knex incorrectly if I'm trying to seed a database. Is there a proper way to seed a database using Knex?